# Adding more key-value pairs in Map<String, String> of List<Map<String, String> > while iterating list

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am getting List< Map < String, String > > from an API. I need to iterate through every map elements in List and add more items in Map.

Here is how I am doing.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = someAPI.getList();
for(Map<String, String> m : list )
{
    m.put("Key1", "Value1" );
    m.put("Key2", "Value2" );
};

return( list );
```

When I return the list from the function, it doesn't have "Key1" -> "Value1" values in the map. It has original value that came from the API. I want the map elements in the list to be updated with these key-value pairs.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What's your problem? You're already updating the maps in the list.

Comment: Just Edited the original question.

Comment: That's very fishy, a map should update in place. What's the concrete class of these maps (System.out.println(m.getClass().getName())

Comment: Sounds hacky to me, what would happen is someAPI.getList() returned ImmutableMap's? Best not to mutate the result from a service, best to instead create a new list/maps (in my opinion).